# Referencing options menu item as view throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu, showcaseview

I'm building user guide with `MaterialShowcaseView` library. I plan to guide user through all toolbar options menu items in fragment (`Theme.AppCompat` with no action bar is used). Thus I need to reference to each options menu item as view. But unfortunately I receive NullPointerException in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.account_summary_menu, menu);
    View item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).getActionView();
    if(item == null)  Log.d("TAG", "null");

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This works well in `onOptionsItemSelected` method but is not preferred. Any help strongly appreciated.

**UPD:** Fragment code

```
public class AccountSummary extends Fragment {

public AccountSummary() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_summary, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_menu)[0]);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

//Create options menu
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.account_summary_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_filter:
            showPopup();
            return true;

        case R.id.document_share:
            try {
                ExportData.exportSummaryAsCsv(getContext(), prepareCsvData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

}
```

**UPD2** It seams that view is created before menu inflation is finished. I guess I can use workaround like `Thread.sleep()` but is there any more elegant way?

Comment: Hi @burzakovskiy i am facing same issue, my requirement is also same. I am using "mreram:showcaseview" library for user guide. In this i have to pass View object to highlight that part. I am facing problem to find View object of option menu icon (Three dots on top Right Corner) please help me out if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since the fragment equivalent is already giving you a MenuInflater, probably try doing this..

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

May be in your case, `getActivity()` may be throwing a null pointer because the `onCreate` method of Activity is called first, and before it finishes `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called.

Comment: @burzakovskiy could you paste the Fragment code here

Comment: Updated question with fragment code. Helper methods were removed