# How to cast Option Menu as View

Tags: android, view, optionmenu

I am using `showcaseview` library to show user guide.In this i have to pass `View` object to highlight particular view . I am facing problem to find View object of option menu icon (Three dots on top Right Corner).
[I also tried to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791437/referencing-options-menu-item-as-view-throws-nullpointerexception)   but nothing helpfull.

I also tried as `View view=menu.getItem(0).getActionView();` but could not help and always give me exception`Crash Handler uncaughtException:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getLocationOnScreen(int[])' on a null object reference`

Although i am able to find View object of MenuItem like this `View menuItemView1 = findViewById(R.id.menu_edit);`

Please let me know anybody have suggestion

Comment: Use `Activity#findViewById(menu_item_id)`. Options menu view inherit its id from the menu item. This can get tricky though. If the menu is collapsed, this can through NPEs.

Comment: hi @ashu, I am already able to find menu_item_id but i want Option menu as View so i can Highlight that view for User Guide.

Comment: Read the comment again

Comment: You are saying like i should try like this `View main_options_menu = findViewById(R.id.menu_item_id);` ?

Comment: Yeah. Which should return a view

Comment: @ashu when user open the app for the first time then menu would be close and this cause NPEs  so how can we get View object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217824/discussion-between-amit-semwal-and-ashu).

Comment: Sorry, I am extremely occupied at the moment. I did a quick Google search and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614293/android-get-view-reference-to-a-menu-item) came up. It seems to have many solutions to the problem you're referring to.